# How to show term child only if has a post

Tags: terms

I want to show term child only if has a post here is my code,
can you please reply me where i am doing wrong.

```
<li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DESTINOS <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
<?php
$term_id =169;
$taxonomy_name = 'spanishcategory';
$term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

AS per my knowledge you need to write following function in your functions.php and check whether the term has post using the below function

```
function check_term_posts($tax_slug, $term_id) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => spanishcategory,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => 169
            )
        )
    );
    $term_query =  new WP_Query($args);
    $term_posts_count = $term_query->found_posts;
    if( $term_posts_count>0 ){
        return true;// You can code here to echo name of category
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do let me know if this can solve your error or need any help?

Comment: Hi Pratik, Thanks for answer, can tell me please the above my will be same or not ? I added your code in my function.php but  it's not giving me only child if has a post.

Comment: Are you using the function where you need to display the term?

Comment: I got this error after that                                                                               
  : Warning: Missing argument 1 for check_term_posts(), called in /var/sites/s/stagingblog.isango.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/canada/Spanish.php on line 84 and defined in /var/sites/s/stagingblog.isango.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/canada/functions.php on line 727